# How to solve for V0 in the next circuit

Tags: ac

How can I solve for V0 on the next circuit if Z1 = 1, Z2 = j, Z3 = -j.

All the ways I'v tried, V0 depends ends depending on V0, maybe using superposition theorem?

[image]

Attempt 1: ( Calculating current through Z3, and use a current divider to get the current through Z1 or Z2, then multiply times the impedance used.)

[image]

Attempt 2: (Using net analysis for determining I1, I2 and I3, then multiplying (I2-I1) * Z2)

[image]

I need to measure what 2V0 is to solve for the impedance of the 1A source, Thanks!

Comment: Show the "ways you tried".

Comment: Sure, I was about to :)

Comment: Is it assumed that these are DC sources?  And V0 referenced to where?

Comment: @Aaron I am sorry yes these are dc sources, because I am trying to calculate Thevenin's equivalent impedance, and ground is the bottom node.

Comment: How does DC current flow through Z3?

Comment: Isn't it like cap will be open ckt for DC voltage and hence all the 1A will flow though 2V0 voltage source?

Comment: Notice there is only one unknown in this circuit, Vo, so only one equation is necessary to solve for it.